# kohana 3 - doesn't display anything for hello world controller

Tags: php, kohana

I upload the kohanav3 to server and use its default contoller, Controller_Welcome in application/classes/controller/welcome.php, however it display empty result in all browser.
After checking I find out they put the "ob_start" in /system/classes/kohana/core.php
after commenting out, it works.

Anyone having the some problem with me?

Comment: Check your web-server logs for php errors.

Comment: I am testing in my local pc xampp.. not sure how can I check it?

Answer (score 1):

http://kohanaframework.org/guide/tutorials.helloworld